# Account Object Validation Rule formula Help

Tags: validation-rule

I am attempting to get this Validation Rule formula to work and enforce the chronological order entry. First i want users to enter `PersonEmail`, then `Email_2__c`, and finally `Email_3__c` for Person Accounts:

> (PersonEmail, Email_2__c, Email_3__c).

Next, I am also trying to enforce this this same chronological entry for Non-Person Accounts as well:

> (Email__c, Email_2__c,Email_3__c)

When i tested this out on a Person account with the following criteria, the validation rule never fired. I am trying to figure out why? Any thoughts on this? Please advise thanks!

- Bypass_Validation_On_Conversion__c = false
- Converted_From_Lead__c = false
- PersonEmail = null
- Email_2__c = 'Test@test.com'
- Email_3__c = null

```
IF( $User.Is_Integration_User__c || $Profile.Name = "B2BMA Integration User", false,OR(
AND(
IsPersonAccount = TRUE,
NOT((ISCHANGED(Bypass_Validation_On_Conversion__c)&&
Bypass_Validation_On_Conversion__c <> true &&
Converted_From_Lead__c = true) || (Bypass_Validation_On_Conversion__c = true &&
Converted_From_Lead__c = true)),
OR(
NOT(ISBLANK(Email_2__c)) && ISBLANK(PersonEmail),
NOT(ISBLANK(Email_3__c)) && ISBLANK(Email_2__c)
)
),
AND(
IsPersonAccount <> TRUE,
NOT((ISCHANGED(Bypass_Validation_On_Conversion__c)&&
Bypass_Validation_On_Conversion__c <> true &&
Converted_From_Lead__c = true) || (Bypass_Validation_On_Conversion__c = true &&
Converted_From_Lead__c = true)),
OR(
NOT(ISBLANK(Email_2__c)) && ISBLANK(Email__c),
NOT(ISBLANK(Email_3__c)) && ISBLANK(Email_2__c)
)
)
))
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stock Exchange (SFSE)! My first piece of advice that does not directly answer your question is to choose either the use of `AND`, `OR`, etc. or the use of `&&`, `||`, etc. Mixing the two can make it harder to read and debug.

Comment: Thank you @Moonpie if I can rewrite this to make better sense I think that would help me better understand where this issue is.

Comment: the way to solve these types of issues is to start with a smaller version of the VR and make it work, then add one condition at a time and test; then rinse and repeat.

Comment: I cannot recommend strongly enough you break this one rule up into multiple, simpler rules.